# How to trigger an observeEvent in shiny when multiple selectizeInput is cleared

Tags: r, shiny

I would like for an `observeEvent` to trigger when the list of inputs is cleared.

Here is a little example app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectizeInput(inputId='select',
                 label='Select something',
                 multiple=TRUE,
                 choices=letters[1:3])
)

server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print(input$select)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Now each time I select another letter the `observeEvent` is triggered. Also removing a letter triggers the event. However, removing the final letter does not seem to trigger anything.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898693/shiny-selectinput-and-selectizeinput) but it does not seem to apply to my case (or I do not manage to get it to work).

So my expected output would be that after selecting `a` it prints `"a"`, but then after deleting `a`, that it prints something as well (be it `NULL` or `""`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`observeEvent` has a number of arguments

> observeEvent(eventExpr, handlerExpr, event.env = parent.frame(),
> event.quoted = FALSE, handler.env = parent.frame(),
> handler.quoted = FALSE, label = NULL, suspended = FALSE, priority = 0,
> domain = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), autoDestroy = TRUE,
> ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = FALSE, once = FALSE)

including `ignoreNULL`, which is set to `TRUE` by default, simply change that to `FALSE`

```
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print(input$select)
  },ignoreNULL  = FALSE)
```

Comment: You may also want to add `ignoreInit = T` so that it doesn't print `NULL` when the page first loads (ie, when nothing has been selected)

Answer (score 4):

You can use observe instead of observeEvent.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectizeInput(inputId='select',
                 label='Select something',
                 multiple=TRUE,
                 choices=letters[1:3])
)

server <- function(input, output){

  observe({
    print(input$select)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```